# Flutter Firebase notification giving multiple error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add FCM notification in my app but its showing too many errors in app.

Here is the log

```
W/ConnectionTracker(25132): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(25132): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@40f6abf
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1759)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1786)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:751)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at lq.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):10)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at lc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(25132):     at ix.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217081@20.42.17 (120400-0):6)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132): Failed to get FIS auth token
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:55)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.startRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:37)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.getToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:13)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$2$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:163)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$4.start(Unknown Source:8)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:14)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$3$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:162)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$1.then(Unknown Source:6)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132): Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:183)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:489)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:360)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2(FirebaseInstallations.java:350)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseInstanceId(25132):    ... 1 more
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132): getToken, error fetching instanceID: 
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132): java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.handleResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:81)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.3.0:91)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.then(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseIidExecutors$$Lambda$0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:15)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown Source:0)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:19)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:86)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Unknown Source:8)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:9)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:7)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:45)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzi.handleMessage(Unknown Source:2)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7584)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin(25132):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/flutter (25132): Firebase Device token: null
```

My app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.lunchbox_admin"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i have added   `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3` in pub.xml

I already to downgrade the com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging. Also delete goog-services.json and download again and replace but don't know why i am getting these errors.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis i have solved this by remove the firebase_messaging package install again and restart my laptop :D

Comment: same issue here, any solid fixes for this yet guys?

Comment: I'm not only seeing this on Flutter, I have a native app showing this on deleteInstanceId()